# Draw the cdf for n=1 and n=2

Tags: probability, statistics

So, I'm trying to find the CDF for n=1 and n=2. I have the random variables $X_1, X_2,...$, which have the distribution $U(|5.5+\frac{1}{n}|)$

Additionally, I need to prove that $X_n \xrightarrow{L}X$, with X=5.

I'm somewhat confused as to the first part, since I've been used to finding CDF's from datasets, not anything like this, but the part I'm having the most trouble with is the proof.

$X_n$ converges to X in distribution is written as $X_n\xrightarrow{L}X$ if for all $x$:

$F_n(x)\rightarrow F(x)$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are there any references of books or web links for this?

Comment: Nothing that isn't in the question I'm afraid.

Comment: It rather depends on what $U(|5.5+\frac{1}{n}|)$ means.  I would guess that the distribution limit was  $U(|5.5|)$ which I would also guess was not $5$